# Submit Button, Execute PHP in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am developing a web app but running into a few small snags. I'm using CodeIgniter.

I want to have 2 buttons that will do execute 2 different functions that do different things to the database. I have these functions made in the proper Controller file.

What is the best way to go about making the buttons execute their respective functions? If it requires javascript, I have no problem making it, just need some pointers as I'm a little bit confused here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're making changes to records in the database, you should probably implement them as part of a form (or two). Potentially destructive actions should not be executable just using a simple GET request.

The form(s) can contain a hidden input type to specify what you want to in the controller.

**HTML page:**

```
<form action="controller/myfunction" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="one">
    <input type="submit" value="Do action one">
</form>

<form action="controller/myfunction">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="two">
    <input type="submit" value="Do action two">
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
function myfunction()
{
    // Your form would be submitted to this method...
    // Get action from submitted form ('one' or 'two')
    $action = $this->input->post('action');
    // Decide what to do
    switch ($action)
    {
        case 'one': $this->my_first_action(); break;
        case 'two': $this->my_second_action(); break;
    }
}

function my_first_action()
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

It would be good practise to redirect to another page once the form has been submitted - use the '[Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)' pattern.

Comment: This is definitely what I'm looking for. The problem now is that even with the function defined in my Controller and it being properly called in form action="" I get a 404 error?

Comment: It sounds like you need to enter the full URL in the form's action tag. Use the URL helper (e.g. <?php echo site_url('controller/method') ?>) or the form helper (<?php echo form_open('controller/method') ?>).

Also make sure the method is set to POST.